# The "Merge" button in TFS-2010 is missing?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

We use `Vs2010`  with `TFS 2010`

The settings for source control [`merge` || `compare` ] are:

[image]

Everything is working fine for `cs` + `aspx` + `html` extensions.

But there is a problem with `css` extension ( and we can't figure why) :

For all **other** files it *DOES* show the `merge` button (when there are conflicts) :

[image]

But for **css** extension files there is **no** Merge button :

[image]

Why is that ? and how can I change it ? (already looked at settings  , but couldn't find any  related section).

---

Additional unrelated info :

- We use *Beyond compare* as our compare tool
- The exact settings for the compare operation :

  - Command: `C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.exe`
  - Arguments `%1 %2 /title1=%6 /title2=%7 /solo`
- The exact settings for the Merge operation :

  - Command: `C:\Program Files\Beyond Compare 3\BComp.exe`
  - Arguments `%1 %2 %3 %4 /title1=%6 /title2=%7 /title3=%8 /title4=%9`

Comment: What is the encoding of that file in each branch?  (As configured in TFS...)  Does the file have any non-Latin1 characters?  Non-UTF8 characters?

Comment: @EdwardThomson How can I check it ? there might be a white space which is not visible ....

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245453(v=vs.80).aspx should be able to assist with determining the encoding.  Sometimes a file gets added wrong accidentally and the encoding is never switched to what it should be...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Connect to your TFS server and go to your Team Explorer panel. Select `Settings->Source Control`

Check if the .css file extension is registered. For me it shows up under the `Common Web Files` category but I am on 2012

Comment: and does this category should have the merge option ? ( I currently have no access so I can't check it)

Comment: Yes, when you add a file type it provides a checkbox to enable file merging. The experience may be a bit different on 2010, which is what you seem to be on.